# How to completely get rid of bug infestations in RimWorld?

Tags: rimworld

I know I can disable the Infestation event in the scenario editor, but that still leaves things like bugs guarding a downed refugee and/or bugs appearing in Revealed Areas in mountains.

Is there a way to completely disable bugs including the events which are not necessarily infestations?

Answer (score 1):

These mods disable / weaken bugs to the point of being essentially a non-threat, so even if they show up, they won't be an issue:

- [ez infestation](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1451980373)

  > This mod makes those damn bugs weak and minimizes the number of bug spawn.
  > your colonist can easily beat those bugs even with bare hands with this mod.
- [No Infestation](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1279817576)

  > Remove infestation event from your game.
  > (in case you always forgot about turning it off in the scenario editor)

Answer (score 0):

Most violent events such as bug infestations and raids are disabled in in "peaceful mode" which was implemented in the Beta 16 release of December 2016 and continued at least through 1.0, the current release as of October 26, 2018. This is your best bet for minimizing bug events.